# How to change unity Lighting Ambient color Intensity at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating 2D game with unity. I set the ambient color at runtime of the Lighting but it is also changes the intensity of the light. how to avoid the lighting intensity value from changing?

```
RenderSettings.ambientLight = new Color(27, 34, 46, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: Show the the code you're suing to change the light color. Also show a screenshot of the property you're trying to change during run-time.

Comment: Yes I am changing light color. with the help of this line RenderSettings.ambientLight = new Color(27, 34, 46, 0); I am changing color from lighting window's Ambient Color. I also updated the question. I want to change the intensity of the HDR Color window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`RenderSettings.ambientLight`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderSettings-ambientLight.html) property is a type of [`Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html) and if you read the documentation, you will see that it takes values from `0f` to `1f` and not `0` to `255`.

[`Color32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32-ctor.html) uses values in the `0` to `255` range:

```
RenderSettings.ambientLight = new Color32(27, 34, 46, 0);
```

But if you really want to use `Color` with `0` to `255` range then just divide it by `255f`:

```
RenderSettings.ambientLight = new Color(27 / 255f, 34 / 255f, 46 / 255f, 0 / 255f);
```